# Will this question be well received here?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, questions, specific-question

Is it beneficial to do one book twice or two book once or repeat the difficult questions from one book. I am asking this in context for preparing for tough  competitive exams such as  Joint entrance exam advanced (IIT JEE) and International Mathematics Olympiad.

Though I am a student who is self studying, I can phrase this question as if it is asked by a teacher to make this question about Mathematics Educators (and not math student). But will this question be well received? Will this be on-topic? Any suggestions on improving the question?

Comment: Mind defining the 2 acronyms?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer they are popular exams. Joint entrance exam(JEE)  and international math Olympiad.

Comment: is JEE specific to India?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer yes!

Comment: I learned, some time ago, that “SAT” the test used to apply to college in the US, wasn’t well known in the rest of the world. Always good to define acronyms when used.

Comment: Well I know that IIT(University) are very famous and respectable around the world, so I thought JEE which is entrance exam for IIT, is also famous. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: I know several IIT graduates but still had not heard of JEE until right now.  For better or for worse, @JoeTaxpayer is right about acronyms on this site, since although the clientele is largely English-speaking, it isn't just US- (or India-)based.

Comment: Always expand all acronyms. This website was the first place where I encountered the term "PEMDAS", for example, and terms like "K-12" are highly culture specific, as are the shorthands for academic institutes.